# Is it possible to limit Gmail search results to unread messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Is it possible to limit Gmail search results to unread messages? This isn't about selecting unread questions from existing search results, which is covered in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/how-do-i-select-unread-messages-in-gmail-without-having-to-click-on-the-arrow-nex). I'm looking for a search flag that works for unread messages the way `label:NAME_OF_LABEL` does for labels.

Comment: (I do actually know the answer to this -- it was easily Googlable -- but I'll hold off on posting it for an hour or two to give someone else a chance at the easy Internet dollars.)

Comment: I'll claim those dollars :)

Comment: @Whitingx, sold for 25 Internet dollars. Your answer actually surprised me, I've been using a slightly different but equally effective method, which I posted as a separate answer.

Comment: @Lord-Torgamus - multiple paths, same destination, lets share those dollars $12.50 each :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the search box, type "label:Unread"

[Using advanced search](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190)

Answer (score 11):

Whitingx's answer is good, but it's not the only answer. The flag `is:unread` works equally well.